# Build on El Capitan; test on Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, macos

A user is reporting a bug when running our Mac application on Mac OS X 8 (Mountain Lion).  I can reproduce this with the shipping version.  I'm trying to build a version for testing a fix, but I seem to be unable to run the debug version on Mountain Lion.  The app is killed immediately and I see the following in the Console:

"killed [app ID] because its use of the com.apple.developer.aps-environment entitlement is not allowed"

In the Capabilities tab in Xcode we **do not** have Push Notifications on.  If I look at the App ID in the portal, it has Push Notifications as "Configurable" but we don't have them enabled.  Nevertheless, I have changed it to disabled.

After regenerating the provisioning profile, I still have the above error about the "com.apple.developer.aps-environment entitlement is not allowed".

This same build works fine when tested on Mac OS X 10.9, 10.10 and 10.11.  I just can't run it on 10.8.

Anyone know what might be going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps this [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2415/_index.html) may provide additional info.

Comment: I had looked at that previously.  What I found useful was how to dump a provisioning profile to see what entitlements were in it.  Mine has   <key>com.apple.developer.aps-environment</key>
  <string>development</string>  Which I believe is causing my problem running on Mountain Lion.  However, I don't know why this is in there since I have made sure the App ID does not request that entitlement.